# How to sort hours in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timestamp

I have a table called `Transaction`. In that a column `Time` with `TimeStamp` datatype is found.

So the data will be looking like `2015-01-17 08:12:48.000`

I want to display like `8 am`

For example

```
`2015-01-17 08:12:48.000`  `8 AM`
`2015-01-17 14:12:48.000`  `2 PM`
```

now i got the result like above. This is my result

```
Hour
----
01 PM
02 PM
04 PM
05 PM
06 PM
07 AM
07 PM
08 AM
09 AM
10 AM
11 AM
12 PM
```

This is the query for above result.

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(CAST(Time as datetime),'hh tt') hour,
    COUNT(TransactionNumber) Total_Transaction,
    SUM(Total) salesCost
FROM 
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction]
WHERE 
    StoreID = '1001' 
    AND YEAR(Time) = '2015' 
    AND MONTH(Time) = '01' 
    AND DAY(Time) = '15'
GROUP BY
    FORMAT(CAST(Time as datetime),'hh tt')`
```

Now I want to sort the hours. It should display like

```
07 AM
08 AM
09 AM
10 AM
11 AM
12 PM
01 PM
02 PM
.
.
07 PM
```

Thanks

Comment: The `timestamp` datatype in SQL Server has **absolutely nothing** to do with a date & time - it's a simple, server-based **binary counter** .....

Comment: I'm *hoping* you mean `datetime` here, not `timestamp`; if you're using `timestamp`, the value  is meaningless (note: technically `timestamp` is obsolete - it is now an alias to `rowversion` - the type was renamed to avoid exactly this confusion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to the end of your statement:

```
, convert(varchar(2), [time], 8)
order by convert(varchar(2), [time], 8)
```

Resulting in this:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT(CAST(Time as datetime),'hh tt') hour,
    COUNT(TransactionNumber) Total_Transaction,
    SUM(Total) salesCost
FROM 
    [HQMatajer].[dbo].[Transaction]
WHERE 
    StoreID = '1001' 
    AND YEAR(Time) = '2015' 
    AND MONTH(Time) = '01' 
    AND DAY(Time) = '15'
GROUP BY
    FORMAT(CAST(Time as datetime),'hh tt')
    , convert(varchar(2), [time], 8)
order by convert(varchar(2), [time], 8)
```

`convert(varchar(2),[time],8)` returns the datetime with style `8` in the following format: `hh:mi:ss`, and using `varchar(2)` truncates it to `hh`.

Documentation for [convert and styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

As Shakeer Mirza posted, using `datepart()` works as well.

Documentation for [datepart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx).

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Use `DATEPART` function simply

```
   Select DATEPART(HH, YOUR_DATETIME_COL) AS HR, ......
   ........  --Write your Statements
    ........
   ORDER BY HR
```

`DATEPART` will give result in integer format. So the Order by will give exact order